# Numpy combine all nonzero elements of one array in to another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

In Numpy I have two three dimensional arrays representing images. I'm trying to create an overlay of the second image on to first so I'd like to replace all of the elements in the first array with respective elements from the second array but only when they aren't zero. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use-case for `np.where` ...

```
new_arr = np.where(second == 0, first, second)
```

I've done the replacement out-of-place (creating a new array rather than modifying the original), but that's usually OK...

Comment: This is what I ended up using and it worked well, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
zeros_idx = array2 != 0
array1[zeros_idx] = array2[zeros_idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the original using `numpy.nonzero`.  Similar to answer provided by @Holt .

```
m = numpy.nonzero(array2)
array1[m] = array2[m]
```